# update multiple table refrencing new table data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table called `ADSCHL` which contains the `school_code` as Primary key 
and other two table as `RGDEGR`(common field as `SCHOOl_code`) and `RGENRl(Original_school_code`) which are refrencing the `ADSCHL`.

If a `school_code` will be updated, both the table `RGDEGR (school_code)` and `RGERNL ( original_schoolcode)` has to be updated as well.

I have been provided a new data that I have imported to SQL server using SSIS with table name as `TESTCEP` which has a column name `school_code`. I have been assigned a task to update the old `school_code` value (`ADSCHL`) with new `school_code` (`TESTCEP`) and make sure the changes happen across all 3 tables.

Can someone please help me with this?

I tried using `Merge Update` function but wasn't able to do it. It errored out.

I tried using this query and wasn't sure if this is gonna help me to update all the tables:

```
UPDATE dbo.ADSCHL 
    SET dbo.ADSCHL.SCHOOL_CODE = FD.SCHOOL_Code
FROM dbo.ADSCHL AD 
INNER JOIN TESTCEP FD
    ON AD.SCHOOL_NAME = FD.School_Name
```

Comment: Can you post your code along with the error?

Comment: Update dbo.ADSCHL
SET dbo.ADSCHL.SCHOOL_CODE = FD.SCHOOL_Code
FROM dbo.ADSCHL AD
INNER JOIN TESTCEP FD
ON AD.SCHOOL_NAME = FD.School_Name

Comment: I tried using the above query and wasnt sure if this is gonna help me to update all the tables..i am pretty new to SQL so your help will be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't update more that one table in a single statement in SQL Server. You might want to create an after update trigger. So that, once the value is updated in table `dbo.ADSCHL`, it updates the `school_code` value in other two tables.

Comment: can you give me an idea how would that work..or just guide me with basic SQL query ...

Comment: can someone look at the code if this is going to update the record across all tables using Trigger :                                                                    create trigger trUpdateExtraTables on dbo.ADSCHL after update 

as

begin

set nocount on;

merge TESTCEP1;

using (select Inserted.PK, Inserted.School_Code as NewCode, Deleted.School_Code as OldCode

from Inserted inner join Deleted 
ON Inserted.PK = Deleted.Pk) U 
ON mySecondTable.School_Code = U.Old_Code

WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE

SET School_Code = U.New_Code

Comment: @user255826 Please check out my answer below. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't update more that one table in a single statement. However, you could write an instead of update trigger to update the other two tables before the `dbo.ADSCHL` is updated like this:

**Before Update Trigger:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.UpdateSchoolCode ON dbo.ADSCHL
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    --update RGDEGR
    UPDATE rd
    SET rd.school_code = i.school_code
    FROM RGDEGR rd
    INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.school_code = rd.school_code
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.id = d.id;  --primary key join 

    --update RGENRl
    UPDATE rg
    SET rg.school_code = i.school_code
    FROM RGENRl rg
    INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.school_code = rg.school_code
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.id = d.id;  --primary key join

END;
```

Then run this update statement once the trigger is created:

```
--update ADSCHL 
UPDATE ad
  SET ad.SCHOOL_CODE = fd.SCHOOL_Code
FROM dbo.ADSCHL ad
INNER JOIN TESTCEP fd ON ad.SCHOOL_NAME = fd.School_Name;
```

**Note:** I apologize for my comment above, I just realized that you would need a before update trigger rather than an after update one.

Comment: Hi, I am looking at the code and i am not sure what i (insert ) and delete (d) refers to ?

Comment: `Inserted` and `deleted` are pseudo tables that store inserted/deleted values in the same table structure as the underlying table (in your case `dbo.ADSCHL`). Here is a good explanation on what those table means: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2342/understanding-sql-server-inserted-and-deleted-tables-for-dml-triggers/

Comment: i tried using the query you had provided, the first part did execute sucessfully, but when i tried to update the ADSCHL i received as error "(343 row(s) affected)

(1422 row(s) affected)
Msg 3902, Level 16, State 1, Procedure UpdateSchoolCode, Line 26
The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: I removed the commit part (which was optional) from the trigger. Please try it again, it should run fine now.

Comment: Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Comment: @user255826 Did you change the primary key join to match your primary keys in the table? It looks like you have some kind of error.

Comment: YES i did, still receiving same error...good to know ur from nepal, m from nepal too ...:)

Comment: is there a way i could send u an email ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85210/discussion-between-futbolfan-and-user255826).